# How to write a list to a new line in a file for Python

Tags: python, json

```
import json
f = open("Troubleshooting.txt","a")
json.dump(problem,f)
f.close()
```

I've tried using json but it keeps writing the list on a single line which makes it extremely messy.
For example -
json.dump(problem)
Writes in the txt file:
["Phone has gotten wet", "The display is broken", "The phone does not charge", "There is no sound", "The interface is slow", "Nothing is saving"]

Then when the script is restarted with different values:
json.dump(problem)
Simply adds on this to the previous list:
["The phone doesn't turn on", "The phone does not charge"]

Making it all together be one line saying:
["Phone has gotten wet", "The display is broken", "The phone does not charge", "There is no sound", "The interface is slow", "Nothing is saving"]["The phone doesn't turn on", "The phone does not charge"]

Is there any way to make the other parts be written on a new line?

Comment: Why using JSON to write it to a text file\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `f.write('\n')` to add a new line to the file.

I.E. make your code into:

```
import json
f = open("Troubleshooting.txt","a")
f.write('\n')
json.dump(problem,f)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add newlines, like so

```
f = open("Troubleshooting.txt","a")
f.write('\n')
json.dump(problem,f)
f.close()
```

But also you don't necessarily even need to use JSON, if you just want strings you could iterate over the list and write each as a new line.

```
f = open("Troubleshooting.txt","a")
for line in problem:
    f.write(line + '\n')
f.close()
```